# Can I use meaningful parameter names rather than $1, $2 inside postgres function definition?

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters

Can I use the meaningful name that I put on the parameter list, rather than the $1, $2 inside the function definition?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_report_email(
    reportname1 text,
    personid2 integer )
  RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE reportid integer;
BEGIN

    select report_id into reportid from reports where report_name = $1;    

    if (reportid is null) then
    insert into reports (report_name) values($1) returning report_id into reportid;
    end if;

    insert into emails_sent (pid, report_id, date_sent)
    values($2, reportid, now());

END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Yes. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createfunction.html has examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apparently I can just use the parameter name directly without problem inside the function definition. For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_report_email(
    reportname text,
    personid integer )
  RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE reportid integer;
BEGIN

    -- add the report name into reports table if it does not exist
    select report_id into reportid from reports where report_name = lower(reportname);

    if (reportid is null) then
  insert into reports (report_name) values(lower(reportname)) returning report_id into reportid;
    end if;

    insert into report_emails_sent (pid, report_id, date_sent)
    values(personid, reportid, now());  
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```